# Android dev mediaPlayer streaming won't stop after switching activities

Tags: android, audio, stream, mplayer

So I am using a URL to stream audio using mediaPlayer- I can start the stream no problem- and stop it as well...as long as I don't switch activities.

The problem happens when I start the stream...then switch activities....then come back and try to stop it. I get a crash because I think the variable is already null even though mediaPlayer is still running.

I am declaring my mediaPlayer as a public in the main thread- so not sure why it's being seen as null after switching activities.

Here is my code for starting the stream, and closing it:

```
 if(v.getId()==R.id.btnStart){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    AppPrefs appPrefs = new AppPrefs(context);

    if(listening==false){
    appPrefs.set_stream("1");
    txtListen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    listening=true;
    btnStart.setText("Stop Stream");
    String url = "http://streamingurl";
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
    mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    else{
    appPrefs.set_stream("0");
    listening=false;
    if(
    mediaPlayer!=null){mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    btnStart.setText("Start Stream");
    txtListen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }





}
```

Answer (score 0):

ahh- just had to make it a static- forgot that part- Whoops!